# Sorting by one of two fields

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to sort a XML nodeset by one of two fields, conditional on the value in another field.

```
<xsl:for-each select="CampusCourseDeliveryItem">
    <xsl:sort select="OffCampus"/>
    <xsl:sort select="OrganisationName" />
    <xsl:sort select="OffCampusLocation"/>

<!-- code to display node goes here -->
```

What I want is, if `OffCampus='Y'`, use `OffCampusLocation` as the sort key, otherwise use `OrganisationName`.

Example data:

```
<CampusCourseDelivery>
    <CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
        <OrganisationName>Chicago</OrganisationName>
        <OffCampus>N</OffCampus>
        <OffCampusLocation></OffCampusLocation>
    </CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
    <CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
        <OrganisationName>London</OrganisationName>
        <OffCampus>Y</OffCampus>
        <OffCampusLocation>Detroit</OffCampusLocation>
    </CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
    <CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
        <OrganisationName>Seattle</OrganisationName>
        <OffCampus>Y</OffCampus>
        <OffCampusLocation>Berlin</OffCampusLocation>
    </CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
    <CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
        <OrganisationName>Adelaide</OrganisationName>
        <OffCampus>N</OffCampus>
        <OffCampusLocation>Ignore this value</OffCampusLocation>
    </CampusCourseDeliveryItem>
</CampusCourseDelivery>
```

Expected sort order:

```
Adelaide
Berlin
Chicago
Detroit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by the following expression:

```
concat(
substring(OffCampusLocation, 1, string-length(OffCampusLocation) * (OffCampus='Y')),
substring(OrganisationName, 1, string-length(OrganisationName) * (OffCampus='N'))       
)
```

Comment: This *almost* worked... I had to change `OffCampus='N'` to `normalize-space(OffCampus)!='Y'` to handle cases where OffCampus is null. (Which I didn't give an example of in my example data, so fair enough you didn't cater for it.)